# how to solve the lxml error in python 2.7.3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xslt, xslt-1.0, lxml

I downloaded the lxml-3.2.3.tar and extracted. later i isntalled it using the command as python setup.py install. but I am getting erro as below :

> ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.
>
> ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

If I want to install libxml2 and libxslt package then where can I find that ?

Comment: I forgot to mention this- It is windows 7 OS

Answer (score 1):

When compiling libraries sometimes it's required to install some requirements e dependencies like development packages before. That is your case.
LIBXML requires **libxslt1-dev** and **libxml2-dev** (The package name may be different).

On linux (Debian based OS) you could to install this packages like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev python-dev
```

Comment: @sam As you mentioned about `*.tar`I assumed it was linux. Anyway 
same procedure, you need install development packages before. Read the `README` or `INSTALL` file from libxml project.

Comment: In libxml project : there is no packages as you mentioned above

Comment: *...The package name may be different...*